# Eclipse Show History error screen

Tags: eclipse

I am using STS and I am trying to get history on files. When I do "Show History", I am displayed with this popup, which is pretty much useless. I cannot understand what it means or how to get around it. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) fails to open the *History* view to show the history of a file or folder that is shared via SVN (Subversion). The bug could be caused by the Eclipse platform, the Subversive plug-in or a combination of both. The dialog ask you to send an error report to the developer, so they can fix the problem.

Probably the error has already been fixed (see [Eclipse bug 471782](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471782)). So **click *Don't Send***, make sure you **use the latest version** of Eclipse and of the Subversive plug-in and try again. If the error occurs again, please [report it to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: It does some files It does show me history but not in few.

Comment: The _History_ view is used by different team providers (SVN, Git, ...). It's definitely a bug, so please update Eclipse+Subversive to make sure, you do not see an already fixed bug. Which Eclipse version and which Subversive version do you use?